# Any way in Google Play books to reset my location to the beginning of a book?

Tags: google-play-books

If I previously read a book that I bought on Google play, and wish to read it again --- is there a way to tell the Google server to forget about all the progress I made reading the book the first time -- that I want my "last reading location" to be reset to the beginning of the book?

I have tried looking both on the Google Play web-site and on the Google Play Books app on my phone --- and no place do I find the option for doing this. Can anyone help me here?

I have searched and searched and searched on the Internet for a way to do this --- and have found nothing. If there is a way to do this, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Tap in the middle of the screen and a slider will appear at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the progress you made in a book, just go to the begining and start reading again. The next time you open the book it would show you the new location at which you stopped reading.